# Passing one global variable to all methods of a class by default

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

Suppose I have  made  a global variable, global $db3; ($db3 is actually an instentiated object of another class).Instead of passing this global variable to every method one by one,I want to pass this variable to all the methods of a class by default.

My first database class is as

```
class dtb{
public $connection;

public function __construct(){

    $this->connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','new5');

     }

     }
 $db3=new dtb();
```

And second class  is as

```
  session_start();
  $a = new session($db3);

       class user{
         public $db;

          public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;

    }

function login(){
 //global $db3;


 //$db3->show_new();
   $results=mysqli_query($this->db->connection,"select * from user");  //(I want to use $db3 of another class here as resource link)


      }


   }
```

Comment: Use constructor and set $db as class variable, then it will be available for in all method as $this->db

Comment: Using a global variable like that is highly not recommended. Things can get out of hand real quick when you can't determine who edited what on the global variable, and it would affect the rest of your program.

Comment: You can get it anywhere as `$GLOBALS['db3']` if you declare it as `global` in the global scope.

Comment: Use a static variable (static class property in this case). See my answer and never use globals again.

Comment: @Claudrian: A static variable === a global variable.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Static variables are contained global variables. They stay in classes or functions. Globals are not contained and prone to collission. Statics don't collide as each has it's own turf. `statics == globals` but `statics !== globals` ;)

Comment: @Claudrian: Wrong, I can call `class::$static` from **anywhere in the program**. The fact that it doesn't collide with `otherclass::$static` can be compared to the fact that `global $class_static` doesn't collide with `global $otherclass_static`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Sure. Whatever... Let's talk again in a few years, after you learn more OOP and change your mind...

Comment: @Claudrian ... `static` **DOES** equate to `global`. Its use is at best very poor OOP style (read: not OOP but class oriented-programming). At worst its use is a maintainability nightmare. No, you shouldn't use `static` in object-oriented code because `static` is not in any way an OOP concept. Just because you use classes doesn't mean your code is OO.

Comment: @rdlowrey **Is there a difference between** `a private static` and `a global`? No need to answer. Unless you will go through reflection to modify it externally. Or a static in a function which is even harder to reach... Yeap! It's global alright.

Comment: @Claudrian Give me a valid use-case for `private static` instead of just `private` and we'll talk. Like I said, that's simply "very poor OOP style." Your code (which I was referencing) used the global `static public` construction, so don't reference a distinction you didn't make in your answer. **And please stop spouting nonsense about how everyone else needs to learn OOP when your arguments themselves are a bastardization of OOP principles.**

Answer (score 10):

Using global variables is highly not recommended. It hinders readability and maintainability of your app, and may cause you to lose your sanity.

**[See this question for more details.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)**

Pass the variable to the constructor of the class. It would be available to all other methods by accessing `$this->db`.

```
class A {

    private $db;

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function someFunction() {
        $this->db->doSomething();
    }

    /*
     * Etc
     */
}
```

You then proceed to call it by:

```
$db3 = new dtb;
$a = new A($db3);
$a->someFunction();
```

`someFunction()` will have access to the `$db3` instance, as it was passed to the constructor and saved as an object field.

Comment: ,Any other approach of doing this?,I actually want to access the $db3 object,which is of other class,in the function of this class

Comment: @SidraNaeem: How does my solution not work for you? Just pass it in the constructor like so: `$a = new A($db_object);`.

Comment: $Madara,I updated the question content ,and also added My first db class whose object is being used in second class as resource link,Plz also review my simple db class.thanks

Comment: @SidraNaeem: That doesn't change my answer, You simply pass `$db3` in to the constructor, as with my previous comment.

Comment: I changed it ,but it did not being passed.May be I am not doing it in a right way.Would you  plz edit your above answer as a complete code solution.Never mind Please.

Comment: $Madara,it still not able to access the  $connection property which is a resource link,needed as a parameter to mysqli_query

Comment: @SidraNaeem: How are you trying to access it? The correct way is `$this->db->connection`.

Comment: ,plz help me in solving question

Comment: ,plz help me in solving question

Comment: @SidraNaeem: I **still** don't understand where your problem is!

Comment: @I have updated my question content again.I am still unable to pass the resource link to MYsqli_query.

Answer (score 5):

You have a few issues in your code example that are related to what you ask for in your question, so I'd like to highlight them.

The most visible issue is that you don't pass along the database connection object. Instead you wrap it into the type `dtb` only to be unwrapped later on inside each other type, for example in your `user`:

```
function login() {
   ...

   $results = mysqli_query($this->db->connection,"select * from user");
                                  ^--^--- unwrapping
   ...
```

Instead the `user` type should just have the connection. It does not need to know about the `dtb` wrappings:

```
function login() {
   ...

   $results = mysqli_query($this->connection, "select * from user");
                                      ^--- one thing, not one thing and another
   ...
```

Next to that you are not using the OO interface of the `mysqli` extension. Your example code demonstrates quite well that this *needlessly* complicates your code. Let's just do it the mysqli way:

```
function login() {
   ...

   $results = $this->connection->query("select * from user");

   ...
```

As you can see, you can make use of the connection without using specifiy `mysqli_*` functions, but just by using the `query` method of the object.

So this was pretty local now with that single line of code. The `$connection` object needs to come into the `user`, for what you have used so far with your non-OO background global variables. However in object oriented programming, there should be no global variables used in the code of a class. That is because what global variables are in procedural code is the `$this` variable in your classes. `$this` should carry everything the methods in your classes need - if not provided with a methods parameter.

So your diverse classes are *based* on the database connection. You want to have it in each class. A class is initialized in it's constructor method. There you pass in everything as parameters that is needed to initalize the class. Let's take the `user` example class:

```
class User
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(Mysqli $connection) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function login() {
        $resultSet = $this->connection->query("SELECT * FROM user;");
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `User` is initialized in its constructor method `__construct` taking the `Mysqli` connection. That connection can then by used with `$this->connection` because it has been assigned to that private variable.

You can now rest assured that once the class is instantiated, the connection will remain the same. That is useful, too, if you need to open a connection to another database in parallel. Your code will continue to work regardless of how many Mysqli connections you need to create.

So now to the usage:

```
$connection = new Mysqli('localhost','root','','new5');

$user = new User($connection);

$user->login();
```

And that's it. Sure there might be some code between where you create the Mysqli connection object and where you create the user, but all you need to do is to pass the connection along.

This won't stop here, albeit I'm already close to a blog-post here. What you probably would like to do is to even remove the burden of the connection details in each class but instead extend from a base class that is taking care of repetitive database interaction code so that in your higher-level classes you can concentrate more on the work and less on the database details. There are many different ways to do that. Extending from a base class is one of them only. A very simplified example:

```
class Database
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(Mysqli $connection) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    protected function query($sql) {
        return $this->connection->query($sql);
    }
}

class User extends Database
{
    $resultSet = $this->query("SELECT * FROM user;");
}
```

If you for example have a common set of classes that just differs by the names of properties it has, the common base class could contain the code to achieve that and the class extending from it only need to specify the parameters for that.

But as written there are many different way to map classes to a database connection. You sometimes don't want to map them at all. Do what suits you best and play around a little. If you always initialize in the constructor and prevent to use globals (and static class variables which are globals, too), you're staying flexible and you can actually play around a lot better.

And remember: Everybody is cooking with water, there is no magic behind it.

Comment: @hakre,Thanks for ur detailed response.I am shifting from mysql to mysqli,so I must  have to go with mysqli proceedural way,as i already  have about 2000 mysql quries.

Answer (score -2):

set it as a class variable in your constructor

```
Class a{

  public __construct( $db ){
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  function b(){
    $this->db->query();
  }
}
```

Comment: not downvoted you, but what do you expect `$this->db();` to do?

Comment: Whatever it was written to do